# This site can't be reached. When serving laravel app on LAN

Tags: php, laravel, host, lan

I want to run my laravel app on LAN for testing but my app is not reachable when hosted locally by serve command.
I have tried every options like,

`php artisan serve --host=192.168.0.100`   [IP of my device]

`php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0`

`php -S 192.168.0.100:8000 -t public\`

but not helping.
I am getting this response instead
[image]

Though I am able to access app by full path like,
http://192.168.0.100/laravel/MYAPP/public/
but using this I am not getting IP of the client.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are in the folder in which your laravel-folder is when you start your server.  You should be in the folder with your index.php-file when you start the server.
Using the -t parameter you can tell the server which folder is your root-folder. Your first example should be

```
php artisan serve --host=192.168.0.100:8000 -t laravel/MYAPP/public/
```

Also you should rememeber the port-number - in the examples you've provided, only your 3rd example seems to include your port-number.

Comment: I've not specified the port number because it uses port 8000 by default.
And my app resides in laravel folder which is in the htdocs folder
`C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\MYAPP`
So I think I've used the right folder to start the server.
My app is working on my device completely fine with both localhost and device IP.
The problem comes only when I try to run it on another device.
`http://192.168.0.100/laravel/MYAPP/public/` this way it also working but I'm not able to get the client IP address.